# usb3 device detected but not it’s block device

Tags: usb, usb-storage, usb-3, udev

when I plug a usb 3 device on a usb 3 port on [devuan](https://devuan.org), I have only this message from `dmesg` :

```
[354063.866359] usb 1-4: new high-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
[354064.050880] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=1f75, idProduct=0916
[354064.053295] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[354064.055350] usb 1-4: Product: USB DISK
[354064.057197] usb 1-4: Manufacturer:  
[354064.059019] usb 1-4: SerialNumber: 13072956011033
[354064.061503] usb-storage 1-4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[354064.064271] scsi host9: usb-storage 1-4:1.0
[354086.410552] usb 1-4: reset high-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
```

with no block device created neither in `/dev` or `/sys`. I have no problem if I plug it on a usb2 port. I have the same problem on Windows®
It also works if I plug an usb2 device on a usb3 or 3.1 port *(because it is loaded through the usb2 driver)*.

I tried :

```
for i in /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/autosuspend;
do echo 2 > $i;
done
for foo in /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/level;
do echo on > $foo;
done
```

But it had no effects. I also noticed usb2 flash drives on usb2 ports were also loaded with `xhci_hcd`.

My Linux kernel version being `4.5.0-0.bpo.1-amd64` how to enjoy usb3 speed with a usb3 flash disk on Linux ?

Comment: `udevadm monitor` the udev events for both usb2 and usb3 ports. If they are different, look at the udev rules, and find out why the usb3 event is not matched.

Comment: @dirkt : I don’t think this is related to udev. There’s no block device data corresponding to my usb flash disk under`/sys`.

Comment: Overlooked `/sys`, and also overlooked the reset. Hardware problem?

Comment: @user2284570, is this Windows on the same machine/hardware?

Comment: Then it is an obvious suck of devuan driver. It looks like a problem in handling the switch from xHCI (USB3) to HS mode, since the device takes USB2 path.